# How to grab gzipped html files with Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get the content from html file, which is resides in html.gz file.
When I try to hit the URL using Jsoup I'm getting:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of
>   ZLIB input stream     at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
>     at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
>     at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:116)     at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)    at
>   java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)    at
>   org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.readToByteBuffer(DataUtil.java:154)     at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:560)
>     at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
>     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
>     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)     at
>   org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:183)

My code looks like:

```
Document doc= Jsoup.connect("http://XXXXXXX_BIZ_Jun17_10:02:17.html.gz").get();
```

Comment: Similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769127/jsoup-and-gzipped-html-content-android

Comment: Also check : http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Request.html#maxBodySize%28int%29

Comment: I have checked both links already. Its not useful. As he suggested I set Content-Type but its not working

Answer (score 0):

#### STEP 1

Try to download the compressed file manually. Then try to open it with a tool like 7zip. This way you can check for sure if the html.gz file is valid.

- If the file is invalid Then Jsoup is not the culprit and **STOP**
- If file is valid, jump to **STEP 2**

#### STEP 2

Fire up your favorite browser and open its developer console on the Network tab. Download the html.gz file and observe the headers exchanged by your browser.
Add the headers you may have missed to your code.